# SELECT columns based on a subquery results with single statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables in the database: *Artist* and *Filter*. Is there anyway to query columns of *Artist* based on the subquery results of *Filter* in a **single** SQL statement?

Pseudo Code:

`SELECT (SELECT ColumnName FROM Filter WHERE ShowColumn=1) FROM Artist`

- Artist

```
------------------------------------------
| id | FirstName | LastName | Genre      |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | John      | Coltrane | Jazz       |
| 2  | Jimi      | Hendrix  | Rock       | 
| 3  | Ulrich    | Schnauss | Electronic |
------------------------------------------
```

- Filter

```
--------------------------------
| id | ColumnName | ShowColumn |
--------------------------------
| 1  | FirstName  | 1          |
| 2  | LastName   | 0          |
| 3  | Genre      | 1          |
--------------------------------
```

- Expected Results

```
-------------------------------
| id | FirstName | Genre      |
-------------------------------
| 1  | John      | Jazz       |
| 2  | Jimi      | Rock       | 
| 3  | Ulrich    | Electronic |
-------------------------------
```

The best I can have is to use multiple `CASE..WHEN`, but it isn't so elegant and there're some extra annoying NULL fields.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (SELECT ShowColumn FROM Filter WHERE ColumnName='FirstName') THEN FirstName END, 
    CASE WHEN (SELECT ShowColumn FROM Filter WHERE ColumnName='LastName')  THEN LastName  END, 
    CASE WHEN (SELECT ShowColumn FROM Filter WHERE ColumnName='Genre')     THEN Genre     END
FROM Artist
```

Comment: What you are trying doesn't feel right. What exactly is `Filter` for? `SELECT id, FirstName, Genre FROM Artist;` should give the result you expect.

Comment: You seem to be dynamically constructing a SQL query. Shouldn't that be the task of a different programming language? EG: PHP/Java/C#?

Comment: You have make an **Dynamic Query**'.

Comment: @MostyMostacho Agree. I'm just wondering if there is anyway to do it at once.

Comment: My best solution in your case would be relying `NULL` columns to right. And column names wouldn't be correctly assigned. This filtering is normally done by higher level applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in SQLite.

You have to read the columns from `Filter` first, and then to construct a query with those columns.

Answer (score 0):

what about this query:

```
select distinct a.id, a.FirstName, a.Genre 
from Artist a, Filter f 
where f.ShowColumn = 1
```

Comment: PO wants to remove columns dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If your target is formatted output, ie, you don't need a dataset, you can compose a string in first column.

Example for CSV output:

```
SELECT --Header
    'id'
    ||CASE (SELECT ShowColumn FROM Filter WHERE ColumnName='FirstName') WHEN 1 THEN ',FirstName' ELSE '' END
    ||CASE (SELECT ShowColumn FROM Filter WHERE ColumnName='LastName') WHEN 1 THEN ',LastName' ELSE '' END
    ||CASE (SELECT ShowColumn FROM Filter WHERE ColumnName='Genre') WHEN 1 THEN ',Genre' ELSE '' END
UNION ALL
SELECT --Data
    CAST(id AS TEXT)
    ||CASE WHEN mf=1 THEN ','||CAST(FirstName AS TEXT) ELSE '' END
    ||CASE WHEN ml=1 THEN ','||CAST(LastName AS TEXT) ELSE '' END
    ||CASE WHEN mg=1 THEN ','||CAST(Genre AS TEXT) ELSE '' END
FROM Artist
JOIN (SELECT ShowColumn AS mf FROM Filter WHERE ColumnName='FirstName')
JOIN (SELECT ShowColumn AS ml FROM Filter WHERE ColumnName='LastName')
JOIN (SELECT ShowColumn AS mg FROM Filter WHERE ColumnName='Genre')
;
```

Comment: It generates great CVS file, unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for. Thanks anyway.

Comment: As I wrote, other outputs may be written. Do you need a dataset or custom output?